# How does the statistical definition of entropy reduce to $S=k_b \ln (g)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

How can we go from the Gibbs form of entropy $$S=-k_\mathrm B \sum\limits_s P(s)\, \ln P(s)$$ to the Boltzmann form $$S=-k_\mathrm B \ln(w)$$ where $w$ is the multiplicity? Is it simply enough to say that if we assume all micro states are equally likely the former reduces to the latter?

Comment: If $w$  is the multiplicity, then the correct equation is $S=k_B \ln (w)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just have to use that all the microstates have the same probability $P(s)=\frac{1}{w}$. Then

$$S=-k_B \sum_{s=1}^{s=w}\frac{1}{w}\ln ({\frac{1}{w}})=k_B \ln(w)$$